# Creating PageObjects in WebDriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I've been creating PageObjects for WebDriverIO and have been following the ES6 method for Page Object pattern in the WebDriverIO documentation.

However, someone on my team suggested simply making objects of selectors, and then calling those strings in the tests. Is there a good reason why the Page Object pattern returns elements and not string of the selectors?

Comment: if you are using PageObjects for WebDriverIO as in its documentation,the return value is `WebElement` Json Object. Its doesnt return selector , it returns the selected element.  What your team member is suggesting is to create objects of selectors and then pass it to for ex:  `browser.click` or any other `browser.` command

Answer (score 1):

Page Object returns elements instead of just the selector string to allow actions to be called directly on the elements e.g.

```
PageObject.Element.waitForDisplayed()
```

Instead of you doing

```
Browser.waitForDisplayed(PageObject.Element)
```

Which may get lengthy and doesn't chain as well. You can find more actions that can be performed on elements [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForDisplayed.html)

However, you can also get the string of the selector if you want by doing

```
PageObject.Element.selector()
```

Chaining e.g.

```
PageObject.Element.waitForDisplayed().click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is allow you to use the objects directly. So:

`MyPageObject.MyElement.click()`

versus:

`browser.click(MyPageObject.MyElement)`

Just a little less verbose